# Append a range to the end of a field

Tags: importing-exporting

I'm working on a real estate site. We are importing the listings from a csv. In the file, one column is the url for the image and another column is the number of images for that listing. For example Column A would have http://www.realestate.com/image1.jpg and then column B would have 4. The way to view the other images is append the value in column B to column a, so it would be http://www.realestate.com/image1_2.jpg, /image1_3.jpg, etc. Does anyone know if a way to do this automatically when drupal imports the csv? Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is not provided by any of the existing csv-import modules. You need to create a custom module for this.  Should be a trivial task if you're a developer. If you're not, hire a consultant.

Comment: You need to use [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and [feeds_tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper), then restructure your csv file. No need for the count. Just use a character separator in the one column, and map it via feeds_tamper to your multi-value field.